# How to show monthly data in Recharts stacked bar chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts, recharts

I have some data which looks like so:

```html
[
  {
    "CarbonAmount": 120,
    "CarbonDescription": null,
    "Date": "2022-03-14"
  },
  {
    "CarbonAmount": 140,
    "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
    "Date": "2022-04-11"
  }
]
```

What I am trying to do is get it in the format so I can visualize it with recharts. There may be a lot of data and What I want is to show exactly show 12 graphs (each graph for one month) and I want exactly like the picture attached
[image]

I did try to prepare data for the chart but still not sure why I am not able to show monthly data.
example code is available in [this link](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-andras-kjy1gn?file=/src/App.js)

any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because you only focusing on the month, i don't think it is necessary to include day in the `Date` key.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 120,
        "CarbonDescription": null,
        "Date": "2022-03-14"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 140,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-04-11"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 150,
        "CarbonDescription": null,
        "Date": "2022-05-17"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 120,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-06-14"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 150,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-07-18"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 180,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-08-16"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 190,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-09-21"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 210,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-10-18"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 220,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-11-15"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 260,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-12-12"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": -120,
        "CarbonDescription": "Carbon Credit",
        "Date": "2022-01-11"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 20,
        "CarbonDescription": "Solar Panel",
        "Date": "2022-02-08"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": -30,
        "CarbonDescription": "Carbon Credit",
        "Date": "2022-03-22"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": -20,
        "CarbonDescription": "Carbon Credit",
        "Date": "2022-12-12"
    },

    {
        "CarbonAmount": 120,
        "CarbonDescription": null,
        "Date": "2022-01-14"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 140,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-02-11"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 150,
        "CarbonDescription": null,
        "Date": "2022-03-17"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 120,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-04-14"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 150,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-05-18"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 80,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-06-16"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 190,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-07-21"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 66,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-08-18"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 99,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-09-15"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 160,
        "CarbonDescription": "Electricity",
        "Date": "2022-10-12"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": -120,
        "CarbonDescription": "Carbon Credit",
        "Date": "2022-11-11"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": 90,
        "CarbonDescription": "Solar Panel",
        "Date": "2022-12-08"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": -90,
        "CarbonDescription": "Carbon Credit",
        "Date": "2022-03-22"
    },
    {
        "CarbonAmount": -60,
        "CarbonDescription": "Carbon Credit",
        "Date": "2022-12-12"
    }
]

const result = data.sort((a, b) => Number(a.Date.split("-")[1] - Number(b.Date.split("-")[1]))).reduce((p, { CarbonDescription, CarbonAmount, Date }) => {
    Date = Date.slice(0, Date.lastIndexOf("-"))
    const found = p.findIndex(p => p.Date === Date);
    CarbonDescription && (CarbonDescription = CarbonDescription.replace(" ", "_"))
    found !== -1 ? p[found][CarbonDescription] = CarbonAmount : p.push({ Date, [CarbonDescription]: CarbonAmount })
    return p;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

your `fetchData` function should look something like this.

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = jsonData.sort((a, b) => Number(a.Date.split("-")[1] - Number(b.Date.split("-")[1]))).reduce((p, { CarbonDescription, CarbonAmount, Date }) => {
        Date = Date.slice(0, Date.lastIndexOf("-"))
        const found = p.findIndex(p => p.Date === Date);
        CarbonDescription && (CarbonDescription = CarbonDescription.replace(" ", "_"))
        found !== -1 ? p[found][CarbonDescription] = CarbonAmount : p.push({ Date, [CarbonDescription]: CarbonAmount })
        return p;
    }, []);
      setData(result);
  };
```

i did try this in your code sandbox and i think it's working like you're expected.